# Rescale an Image depending on the Raycast hit position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a line renderer and a circle png at the end of the line renderer. When the a raycast hits a collided object, the circle png appears at the end of the line. The problem I am facing is; if the object is 10 meters away, I am able to see the circle png easily but if the collider is less than 4 meters, the image is too big. How can I rescale the image so that if its farther, it stays the same and if its near then it scales down so that it looks similar if its far or near.

`Default Scale of the GreenPoint_Raycast: X, Y, Z: 0.001323662`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class raycastLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject lineRenderer;
    RaycastHit hit;

    public GameObject RightHandAnchor;

    public GameObject GreenPoint_Raycast;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("RaycastTarget");

        if (Physics.Raycast (RightHandAnchor.transform.position, RightHandAnchor.transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.forward), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask)) {

            GreenPoint_Raycast.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = true; 
            GreenPoint_Raycast.transform.position = (hit.point); //position is right, scaling is the problem

            if (hit.collider) {

                    Debug.Log ("Hit: " + hit.collider.name);

                    if (hit.collider.name == "Mesh_1") {
                    } else
                    if (hit.collider.name == "Mesh_2") {
                    } else
                    if (hit.collider.name == "Mesh_3") {
                    } 

            } else {

                lineRenderer.GetComponent<LineRenderer> ().SetPosition (1, new Vector3 (0, 0, 5000));
                GreenPoint_Raycast.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;

            }
        } else {
            GreenPoint_Raycast.GetComponent<Image>().enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The distance of the hit point can be calculated with the raycast hit point as:

```
Debug.Log("hit at distance from RightHandAnchor to object: "+hit.distance);
```

With this, I  would like to rescale GreenPoint_Raycast up/down possibly with Lerp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a simple proportion.

`dist1/scale1 = dist2/scale2`

If you say that on 10 meteres the scale is right (assuming that you measure it with your `dist` variable), we can put those numbers in proportion.

`10 / 0.001323662 = dist / scale`

so the desired scale `= 0.001323662 * dist / 10`

Update:
well, you deleted the calculation of `dist`

But I guess it is `Vector3.Distance(hit.point, RightHandAnchor.transform.position)`

Comment: hey the dist was not required for this. It was completely for different reasons.

Comment: Since I am calculating the position of Green Point as ``` GreenPoint_Raycast.transform.position = (hit.point);```. So I guess depending of the hit.point distance, I can scale it?

Comment: @Saif you wrote "if the object is 10 meters away". 10 metres from what point? I guess you need to calculate distance from that point

Comment: 10 meters from the point of the gameObject "RightHandAnchor". I have updated my code. The distance is right. I only have to scale the gameObject up/down.

Comment: @Saif so yes, you need to calculate second distance from that point too. As I wrote `Vector3.Distance(hit.point, RightHandAnchor.transform.position)`. Full formula will be `scale = 0.001323662 * Vector3.Distance(hit.point, RightHandAnchor.transform.position) / 10f` scale is a `Vector3`, so you need to multiply it by `Vector3.One`